# Day of week algorithm bug?

Tags: java, algorithm, calendar

Hello I made a software that generates HTML calendar. I followed Method 1 algorithm from wiki http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Day-of-the-Week to get exact day of the week in current day for a year. But problem is that there is a bug when it goes from year 2099 to 2100 then in year 2100 it is about one day behind.

My question is... is that algorithm correct? Should it be a day back behind in year 2100? I have no time to wait 85 years to figure this out :(
Also I tried Easter Sunday algorithm and it also generates Sunday on the day it should be Sunday by Day of the week algorithm so I am not sure who has the right, if me or the two correctly generating algorithms.

Here are next years what are buggy in my opinion:
Testing years 0 to 2200
Incorrect day from year to year: 99/100
Incorrect day from year to year: 199/200
Incorrect day from year to year: 299/300
Incorrect day from year to year: 499/500
Incorrect day from year to year: 599/600
Incorrect day from year to year: 699/700
Incorrect day from year to year: 899/900
Incorrect day from year to year: 999/1000
Incorrect day from year to year: 1099/1100
Incorrect day from year to year: 1299/1300
Incorrect day from year to year: 1399/1400
Incorrect day from year to year: 1499/1500
Incorrect day from year to year: 1699/1700
Incorrect day from year to year: 1799/1800
Incorrect day from year to year: 1899/1900
Incorrect day from year to year: 2099/2100

*EDIT
Here is algorithm to get Easter Sunday:

```
int c = year/100;
int n = year - 19*(int)(year/19);
int k = (c - 17)/25;
int i = c - (int)(c/4) - (int)((c - k)/3) + 19*n + 15;
i -= 30*(int)(i/30);
i -= (int)(i/28)*(1 - (int)(i/28)*(int)(29/(i + 1))*(int)((21 - n)/11));
int j = year + (int)(year/4) + i + 2 - c + (int)(c/4);
j -= 7*(int)(j/7);
int l = i - j;
int m = 3 + (int)((l + 40)/44); //Your month when is Easter Sunday
int d = l + 28 - 31*(int)(m/4); //Your day when is Easter Sunday
```

Here is algorithm to get day of the week in a Year Month Day

```
int [] CENTURY_TABLE = {0, 5, 3, 1};
int [] MONTH_TABLE = {0, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5};
boolean leap = false;
int t1 = (day + MONTH_TABLE[month - 1]) % 7;
int m1 = year % 100;
int t2 = (m1 % 7) + (m1/4) + CENTURY_TABLE[((int)(year/100)) % CENTURY_TABLE.length] - (leap  &&  (month == 1  || month == 2) ? 1 : 0);
if(t2 == -1){
    t2 = 6;
}
int d = (t1 + t2) % 7;  //0 - Saturday, 1 - Sunday, 2 - Monday... 6 - Friday
```

*FIX
Change "leap" summary in Day of Week algorithm to

```
leap = year % 4 == 0  &&  (year % 100 == 0 ? year % 400 == 0 : true) //This fixed my problem <3
```

Comment: post the code for algorithm

Comment: Off-topic: don't separate lines with `<br>`. To create [linebreaks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#linebreaks) end your line with two spaces and move to next line. You can find more help with editing at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Jigar Joshi Ok added algorithm codes

Comment: @Pshemo I dont understand what is wrong on using `<br>` tags

Comment: @MartinKrajčírovič It works, but it is harder to edit later, especially if you would want to change this text into code example where `<br>` will be treated as code fragment.

Comment: @Pshemo dont worry I am not on that bad to incorrectly use `<br>` code.

Comment: Another thing is that using `<br>` may confuse other editors who may miss fact that you placed that line break tag, so instead of correcting your post they may actually complicate it. Anyway it is your choice how you want to write your question, but generally it is better to use convention also used by others, just to be safe (also `space, space, enter` is easier to write than `<` `b` `r` `>` :)

Comment: @Pshemo it is stupid... if I press 2 times enter then it put my text to something like new paragraph and leaves an ugly mega space between text.

Comment: I am not saying about pressing `enter` twice (which is meant to separate paragraphs). I am saying about pressing `space` twice and then pressing `enter`. Like `foo[space][space][enter]bar` which will generate same result as `foo<br>bar` but IMO is easier to maintain.

Comment: @Pshemo Oh well I misread your first comment... maybe I was programming too much for today I should get some sleep. Anyway thank you for your help with double space = new line

Comment: Double space + enter, lets not forget about enter :)

Comment: @Pshemo Oki then. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your program is affected by leap years: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year

You have a problem on all years dividable through 100 but not 400.

Edit after select as solution:

The code works without problems. I slightly changed for a test and got no error:

```
@Test
public void dayTest()
{
    for (int y = 2099; y <=2100; y++)
    {
        int day = easterSundayDay(y);
        int month = easterSundayMonth(y);

        assertTrue("Wrong year: " + day + "."+ month + "."+ y + " is day: " + dayOfWeek(day, month, y), 1 ==dayOfWeek(day, month, y));
    }
}

public int easterSundayDay(int year)
{
    int c = year/100;
    int n = year - 19*(int)(year/19);
    int k = (c - 17)/25;
    int i = c - (int)(c/4) - (int)((c - k)/3) + 19*n + 15;
    i -= 30*(int)(i/30);
    i -= (int)(i/28)*(1 - (int)(i/28)*(int)(29/(i + 1))*(int)((21 - n)/11));
    int j = year + (int)(year/4) + i + 2 - c + (int)(c/4);
    j -= 7*(int)(j/7);
    int l = i - j;
    int m = 3 + (int)((l + 40)/44); //Your month when is Easter Sunday
    int d = l + 28 - 31*(int)(m/4);

    return d;
}

public int easterSundayMonth(int year)
{
    int c = year/100;
    int n = year - 19*(int)(year/19);
    int k = (c - 17)/25;
    int i = c - (int)(c/4) - (int)((c - k)/3) + 19*n + 15;
    i -= 30*(int)(i/30);
    i -= (int)(i/28)*(1 - (int)(i/28)*(int)(29/(i + 1))*(int)((21 - n)/11));
    int j = year + (int)(year/4) + i + 2 - c + (int)(c/4);
    j -= 7*(int)(j/7);
    int l = i - j;
    int m = 3 + (int)((l + 40)/44); //Your month when is Easter Sunday
    int d = l + 28 - 31*(int)(m/4);

    return m;
}
public int dayOfWeek(int day, int month, int year)
{
    int [] CENTURY_TABLE = {0, 5, 3, 1};
    int [] MONTH_TABLE = {0, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5};
    boolean leap = false;
    int t1 = (day + MONTH_TABLE[month - 1]) % 7;
    int m1 = year % 100;
    int t2 = (m1 % 7) + (m1/4) + CENTURY_TABLE[((int)(year/100)) % CENTURY_TABLE.length] - (leap  &&  (month == 1  || month == 2) ? 1 : 0);
    if(t2 == -1){
        t2 = 6;
    }
    int d = (t1 + t2) % 7;

    return d;
}
```

Comment: It should not be affected by leap years... it also counts with 29 days for February on every `year % 4 == 0`

Comment: Anyway: test Easter Sunday algorithm then place the month and day you got from Easter Sunday algorithm to the day of the week algorithm and you get Sunday so it should be correct...

Comment: You get the message for all years 1400, 1500, 1700, 1800 (leap year) but not 1600 (common year). Using more speaking variable names t1, m1, t2, ... may help to understand the code.

Comment: variable names t1 m1 t2 are just names to store a value there is no deep meaning. I followed algorithm from wiki as I said and I had to store some values somewhere... so there is no meaning why they are t1 m1 and t2. If I would want I just put them to a giant one line code.

Comment: I used m1 to get range 0 to 99 from a century

Comment: I vote for a leap year problem. :D `leap` variable is never changed by the code.

Comment: Instead voting, bring the solution.

Comment: Anyway, why it should have 28 days in February on year 2100 if every 4th year is 29 days in February. So if year 1992 was leap then ofcourse year 2100 is leap too...

Comment: Okay my bad... lol I didnt even notice they removed exactly these years from gregorians calendar for errors Cool.

Comment: Yes calendar was correct from March to December but was always incorrect from January to February on the specific century. I updated my question about the answer that fixed my mistake.

Comment: Also thank you for your help with mentioning leap years.